# How to know which is city and zip latitude and longitude information

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Am sending zip code to google api and trying to capture the response.

Am getting the response. Till this point it is fine

but I want to store the latitude and longitude information for city and zip code in database, but I am not able to understand which is belonging to city and zip code from the response i am getting

```
"geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.75285390,
                  "lng" : -73.9901340
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7509920,
                  "lng" : -73.99346389999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.75184549999999,
               "lng" : -73.99163440
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.75327193029149,
                  "lng" : -73.9901340
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.75057396970850,
                  "lng" : -73.99346389999999
               }
            }
         }
```

this is a snippet of response that i am getting. From this how can u distinguish which is city lat-long values and which is zip code lat-long values?

Comment: I dont know why this qus is downvoted.since i was not able to understsnd which is zip code lat-long i posted this.but instead of answering its downvoted. Can anybody help me with some knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Not a big mistery:

```
var latitude = geometry.location.lat;
var longitude = geometry.location.lng;
```

Comment: which one is related to city and which one is related to zip?

Answer (score 0):

The coordinate is stored in the location property

```
 "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.75184549999999,
               "lng" : -73.99163440
            }
```

Keep an eye on the:

```
"location_type" : "APPROXIMATE"
```

It indicates that the location is not exact. It points to the nearest result. If you ask for an address with a street number and that number doesn't exists on google's database, it returns the closest one.

Comment: i want both city and zip code lat-long values.How to get that

Comment: @zamil For cities there are plenty REST free services that returns city and ZIP from coordinates. Try REST services from http://www.geonames.org/ You can see [Here](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) a list of the available webservices.

Comment: @zamil Another service is Yahoo PlaceFinder (max 50000 requests/dat) http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/guide/requests.html